# ModuleFinder reporting missing modules for 1 line script?

Tags: python

With this very simple testscript.py:

```
import os
```

ModuleFinder is reporting several missing modules:

```
import modulefinder

finder = modulefinder.ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script('testscript.py')
missing, maybe = finder.any_missing_maybe()

print "missing: " + str(missing)

print "maybe: " + str(maybe)
```

Output:

```
missing: ['_emx_link', '_subprocess', 'ce', 'msvcrt', 'nt', 'org.python.core', 'os.path', 'os2', 'riscos', 'riscosenviron', 'riscospath']
maybe: []
```

(my Python environment seems to work fine, and this testscript.py run fine with no errors).

This 'missing' list not being empty prevents me from using the list to determine if there is anything I actually need to try to handle. Can anyone explain why it is not empty or how I could further distinguish "actually missing" modules (like imports of custom .py files that are not present) from these that don't seem to matter?

Comment: Are all your modules located in your sys.path?  If not, you can specify a list of directories to search for modules using the _path_ parameter in the ModuleFinder constructor.. hope this helps.

Comment: @d_rez90 It sounds like the 'path' parameter of the constructor would specify additional places to search for modules, right? These things that it is reporting as missing I am not even requesting explicitly, so I'd assume that they are *supposed* to be in the sys.path, like in the core Python packages?